# Поехал весь контент в табах, что делать?

Tags: html, css, css3, битрикс, tabs

Пробовал различные табы, начиная от чистого css и заканчивая бутстраповскими и jQuery.
Как только добавляется больше 90 заказов, контент весь уезжает вниз под сами табы...
+ если подключить пагинацию в компоненте, то в любом случае все будет ехать. Прошлый раз даже спецом отключали её...
Верстка ломается везде, во всех абсолютно. Не понимаю что делать... прошу помочь.

[image: Вот так должны открываться.]
[image: Вот что произошло...]
[image: Сам код]
Дальше идет компонент и секция закрывается.

```css
.tabs {
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  color: #aaa;
  background-size: cover;
  border-radius: 3px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  margin: 0px 12px 23px -40px;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 220px;
  min-width: 320px;
  max-width: 800px;
}


/* Стили секций с содержанием */

.tabs>section:not(.content-tab_order) {
  display: none;
  padding: 15px;
  background: #fff;
  margin-left: 36px;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 7px;
  min-width: 862px;
  min-height: 360px;
}


/* Прячем чекбоксы */

.tabs>input {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
}


/* Стили переключателей вкладок (табов) */

.tabs>label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 292px;
  margin-left: 52px;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-align: left;
  color: #aaa;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border-width: 2px 0;
  border-style: solid none;
  border-color: #ebebeb #000 #ebebeb;
}

.tabs>label:hover {
  background-color: #43d7f4;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* Стили для активной вкладки */

.tabs>input:checked+label {
  color: white;
  border-top: 1px solid #43d7f4;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  background: #43d7f4;
}


/* Активация секций с помощью псевдокласса :checked */

#tab1:checked~#content-tab1,
#tab2:checked~#content-tab2,
#tab4:checked~#content-tab4,
#tab5:checked~#content-tab5 {
  display: block;
}

#tab3:checked~.content-tab_order,
#tab3:checked~#content-tab3 {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

[image: Вот что я обнаружил]

Получается так, что не пойми откуда берется еще один section... в итоге 1я секция работает, а все остальные уходят вниз.
Открылась секция, в неё залез container block_mobile_container с первой секцией у которой id-content-tab1, а все остальные пролетели мимо...
Дело в том, что в коде это секции нет и быть не должно(

Answer (score 2):

Решение нашлось! На работе подсказали. Проблема была в самой навигации битрикса
В компоненте: sale personal order list

Из-за кривой пагинации, компонент сам закрывал секцию.

```html
<div class="pegen_orders">
<? echo $arResult["NAV_STRING"];?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

На блок из которого вываливается навешайте `overflow: auto`